# Python stack simulation using list structure but not list methods

Tags: python, list, stack

How would you go about simulating a stack's push and pop functions WITHOUT using list methods?

So far I have something like this, but I am not sure as to whether this would work:

```
stack = []

def Push(stack, element):
    stack[len(stack)] = element

def Pop(stack):
    element = tos
    stack[len(stack) - 1] = None

    return element;
```

Would push work, dynamically adding to the list in this manner, and would len update appropriately?

For pop, how would you go about "deleting" from the stack without using any of the list functions?

Comment: `stack[len(stack)]` will always fail if `stack` is a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this **(warning: this is a naive implementation - it doesn't perform checks on the arguments passed)**:

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = [] # Allocate an empty list

    def push(self, ele):
        self._stack += [ele] # Use list concatenation to emulate the `push` operation

    def pop(self):
        last = self._stack[-1:] # Return the last element of the list (also works for empty lists)
        self._stack = self.stack[0:-1] # Copy the elements from the beginning of the list to the last element of the list
        return last # return the last element

    # All stacks should have the `size` function to determine how many elements are
    # in the stack:
    def size(self):
        return len(self._stack)

    # Occasionally you'll want to see the contents of the stack, so we have to
    # implement the `__str__` magic method:
    def __str__(self):
        return '[%s]' % ','.join(map(str, self._stack))
```

NOTE: This method doesn't use any of the `list` methods as `append` and `pop`.

EXAMPLE:

```
s = Stack()

# fill the stack with values:
for i in xrange(10):
    s.push(i+1)

print s # Outputs: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

s.pop()
s.pop()

print s # Outputs: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: @elykl33t: I loathe to be pedantic, but it's not necessarily sublists, but rather *slicing*. ;) Also: you're more than welcome and, thank you as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the intention of this exercise is to look at stacks as an [abstract data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).  You could implement them without using lists at all.  If you insist on using lists, I'm not sure what you mean by "not using list methods".

A stack (as a list) is a data type with two constructors: (a) an empty stack, and (b) the result of pushing an element onto a stack.  You can come up with a lot of different implementations of these two in Python.  E.g., `None` could be the empty stack and `(x, s)` could be the result of pushing `x` on top of `s`.  I suggest that you try to do something like this on your own, before looking for more help.

Answer (score 0):

You could preallocate a list:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self, max_items):
        self.data = [0] * max_items
        self.max_items = max_items
        self.top = -1

    def push(self, i):
        self.top += 1
        if self.top < self.max_items:
            self.data[self.top] = i
        else:
            self.top -= 1
            raise ValueError("stack is full")

    def pop(self):
        if self.top >= 0:
            i = self.data[self.top]
            self.top -= 1
            return i
        else:
            raise ValueError("stack is empty")

    def __len__(self):
        return self.top + 1
```